Automatically transfer data from the same cell in different sheet tabs to one table
I'm currently attempting to make an invoice template with a built in log that will allow me to just duplicate a template tab, rename to invoice number and then output the total owed to a logs tab to keep track of what i am owed and when i received the check.
Currently, the setup has it, so the total is always in Cell D21, but it'd be cool to just store the total to a value and output it to the log so it didn't always read the same cell.
I'm currently having to manually go through and put ='tab name'!D21 in each tab of the rows which is annoying. I tried dragging down to each other row but it only adds 1 to the cell number rather than the sheet name (in hindsight this was obvious) is there a way for me to solve this?

You can input the sheet names into one column in your logs tab, say column A: Invoice 1, Invoice 2, etc. and then you can use the INDIRECT() function to turn the strings/values in column A (Invoice 1, Invoice 2, etc.) into a variable.
Since your data in each sheet is following a template, you'd easily be able to ctrl+d down the same cell value, but for different sheet names.
For example, if your values were in cell B2 in sheet "Invoice1" and sheet "invoice2":
 Column A     Column B
 Invoice1     =INDIRECT(A1&"!$B$2")
 Invoice2     =INDIRECT(A2&"!$B$2")

For a more customizable approach I would recommend reading into Apps Script
Reference Material:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets


If I understand correctly, you have a spreadsheet with n number of sheets.
From each sheet, you want to copy a specific cell and use it to populate a table in another sheet of the same spreadsheet.
And you are currently doing this manually for each row in the target column.
It would be helpful to have an illustrated example of the spreadsheet structure to make the question clearer.
Additionally, it would also help to know what tools you want to use for this (I.E formulas only, macros, apps script, etc.)
With formulas, we can resolve cell references using the INDIRECT function [1].
Here’s an example:
Consider a spreadsheet with 6 sheets and, we want to copy the value of A1 of the first 5 sheets.
In Sheet6 we can use the formula: =INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()&"!A1")
Which for each row will resolve to something like: =Sheet1!A1 depending on the row number the formula is in.
So you can just place it in the top row and drag down.
This assumes your tabs have an incremental number convention which you can consider doing to facilitate the process.
INDIRECT
[1] https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en
You can also use apps script to:

Get all sheets
For each sheet, read the value of a cell
Write the value to the last row in a particular column in another sheet.

This would not need a particular naming convention across the sheets but needs you to set up the script.
For example:
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function pupolateColumnFromSheets() {
 let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 let sheets = ss.getSheets();
 
 for (let i=0; i < sheets.length-1; i++) {
   let value = sheets[i].getRange('A1').getValue();
   let lastSheet = sheets[sheets.length-1];
   lastSheet.getRange(`A${lastSheet.getLastRow()+1}`)
     .setValue(value);
 }
}

This function copies the value of a particular cell from all sheets and writes it to the A column in the last sheet.
It doesn’t depend on the names of the sheets, but it does assume you want to write the value to the last sheet in the document.
A drawback is that there’s no cell reference, but it can be adjusted to write the formula instead of the values.
You can also set  the target sheet name with this approach.
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const targetSheetName = "Sheet6";
const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);

function pupolateColumnFromSheets() {
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();

  sheets.forEach((sheet) => {
    let sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if(sheetName != targetSheetName) {
      targetSheet.getRange(`A${targetSheet.getLastRow()+1}`)
        .setValue(`=${sheetName}!A1`);
    }
  });
}

In this last example, we write a formula to a particular column of a target sheet which references a specific cell from all other sheets.
I have prepared some sample spreadsheets for you.
Formulas example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14FwIA7dfg5M6YtNf95JU4FsPt4iEZte97ExalRLuB8o/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Apps Script Example: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10EZY1e5-6L8CryTF1cIBDC1hV-Q5jOorPKhlxMBV_UM/edit?gid=0#gid=0
I hope this helps!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
